# Prove that if $n$ is odd, then there is a number $x$ such that $x^n+\phi(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\phi:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}}=\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}{\frac{\phi(n)}{x^n}}=0$$
Prove that if $n$ is odd, then there is a number $x$ such that $$x^n+\phi(x)=0$$

My attempt: My aim is to prove that $\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=-1$ by using Intermediate Value Theorem. So I have to formulate an inequality such that $A<-1<B$. The reason I come out of this is since we are dealing with limits which approach to infinity, we can have an inequality which relate the function $\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}$ and constant. But I fail to produce such inequality. Can anyone here guide me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(x) = \frac{x^n+\phi(x)}{x^n}$. As $x \to \pm\infty$, $h(x) \to 1$. Obviously $x^n+\phi(x) = x^n h(x)$. Now all we have to do is remember that as $x \to \pm \infty$, $x^n \to \pm \infty$ (because $n$ is odd).

Comment: But how do we show that $h(x)=0$ for some $x$?

Comment: You don't need that. $x^n+\phi(x)$ tends to $\pm \infty$, so it reaches $0$.

Comment: Can you explain further ? I don see why when $x^n + \phi(x)$ tends to $\infty$, it reaches $0$.

Comment: As $x \to \infty$, $x^n+\phi(x) \to \infty$. Therefore there is $x_1$ such that $x_1^n+\phi(x_1) > 1$. As $x \to -\infty$, $x^n+\phi(x) \to -\infty$, so there is $x_2$ such that $x_2^n+\phi(x_2) < -1$. Use the Intermediate Value Theorem in $(x_2,x_1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $|x|$ is small, $|1/x^n|$ is big. This will be very useful for making your idea work, except there is one special case where this idea won't work. (but that special case is easy....)