# Spivak's Calculus Chapter 7 "Three Hard Theorems", Problem *15a: Prove that if $n$ is odd, then there is a number $x$ such that $x^n + \phi(x)=0$.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Problem 15a of Chapter 7 of Spivak's Calculus asks:

> Suppose that $\phi$ is continuous and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}
>  \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}
>  \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=0$.
>
> a) Prove that if $n$ is odd, then there is a number $x$ such that $x^n + \phi(x)=0$.

I saw [this very elegant proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360338/prove-that-if-n-is-odd-then-there-is-a-number-x-such-that-xn-phix-0), and I understand the proof in the solution manual completely, and I will reproduce a more verbose version of part of it below. Then, I will show the solution I came up with before looking at the manual. Since my proof differs from the manual, I'd like to know if it is correct.

**Solution Manual Proof**

Since $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=0$, by definition we have:

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N > 0\ \forall x\ (x>N \implies \left |\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n} \right |<\epsilon\tag{1}$$

Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$.

Let $N$ be a number such that $\forall x\ (x>N \implies \left | \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n} \right |<\frac{1}{2})$

Let $b$ be a number such that $b>N$.

Then

$$\left | \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n} \right |<\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{-1}{2}<\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}<\frac{1}{2}$$

$$0<\frac{1}{2}<1+\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}$$

$$0<\frac{b^n}{2}<b^n(1+\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}) = b^n+\phi(b)$$
$$0 < b^n+\phi(b)\tag{2}$$

We can now use similar steps to deduce the statement that  for some number a

$$a^n+\phi(a)<0\tag{3}$$

I won't reproduce this part of the proof here, as it is analogous to the first part, though it is important to note that it uses the other two premises of this problem, namely that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=0$$

and that $n$ is odd.

Using the fact that $f(x)=x^n+\phi(x)$ is continuous, together with $(2)$ and $(3)$, using a version of the Intermediate Value Theorem we can conclude that $\exists x \in [a,b], f(x)=x^n+\phi(x)=0$

**My Proof**

Assume $n$ is odd for purposes of a conditional proof.

Since $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=0$, by definition we have:

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N > 0\ \forall x\ (x>N \implies \left | \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n} \right |<\epsilon\tag{1}$$

Let $\epsilon=1$.

Then $\exists N > 0\ \forall x\ (x>N \implies \left | \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n} \right |<1)$

Let $N$ be one such number: $N>0$ and $\forall x\ (x>N \implies \left | \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n} \right |<1)$

Let $x_1$ be a number such that $x_1>N>0$.

Then

$$-1<\frac{\phi(x_1)}{x_1^n}<1$$

$$-x_1^n<\phi(x)<x_1^n$$

Since $n$ is odd, then $-x_1^n=(-x_1)^n$.

$$(-x_1)^n<\phi(x)<x_1^n$$

Multiply each term by $-1$:

$$(-x_1)^n<-\phi(x)<x_1^n$$

Let $f(x)=x^n$. Then we have

$$f(-x_1)<\phi(x)<f(x_1)$$

Since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ it is continuous on $[-x_1,x_1]$.

Therefore, using a version of the Intermediate Value Theorem, we can assert that

$$\exists x \in [-x_1,x_1], f(x)=x^n=-\phi(x)$$

Hence, $\exists x, x^n+\phi(x)=0$

Therefore, we can conclude (by conditional proof) that

$$n\ odd \implies \exists x, x^n+\phi(x)=0$$

Note that I did not use one of the assumptions, namely $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=0$.

Comment: I must be missing something, but with $\phi(x) = 1$ for all $x$ the conditions are satisfied but clearly $\phi(x) >0$ for all $x$.

Comment: The problem is asking for a proof that for a generic $\phi(x)$ that is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, given the assumptions, we can find an $x$ such that $x^n+\phi(x)=0$. For your function $\phi(x)=1$ this is certainly true for an odd $n$. For any odd $n$, $(-1)^n + 1 = 0$.

Comment: The question was edited after my comment.